# Does a MediaPlayer need to be put in a Service?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-mediaplayer

I've read tutorials mentioning that a `MediaPlayer` (Android) needs to be put in a `Service` so it won't be cleaned up. This seems contrary to what I see, which is that even when my app sleeps and I'm using another app or even when the screen is locked - my app's `MediaPlayer` continues playing, presumably because its WakeMode is set to Partial.

Or do we need it in a service in case the app itself gets terminated? But won't that terminate the service as well even if it's in a service?

Comment: By termination, what do you mean? Is it closing the app by pressing back button or swiping the app from the recent apps list? Though both calls Activity onDestroy, the former can be prevented by coding it to onStop. However the service depends on how you started it (startService, bindService,CONTEXT_AUTO_CREATE,mediaBrowser.connect) and how you stopped it(if any).

Answer (score 1):

'Or do we need it in a service in case the app itself gets terminated? But won't that terminate the service as well even if it's in a service?': If you have used startService with startForeground and not used stopService or stopSelf, then NO in any case (even if app is terminated).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know services are high priority which makes them work even if the app is completely closed. But you may be have to define your service high priority when you create it, I'm not sure of it. And services take a lot of resources so It's better to provide a stop button, like a constant notification in notification drawer.

Answer (score -1):

Just need a `Service` if you want play music and your app will be in background.

To do this  you need to embed the `MediaPlayer` in a `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` service and have it interact with a `MediaBrowserCompat` in another activity.

Comment: When my app is sleeping in the background the music doesn't stop, though it's not in a Service.

Comment: How you  want stop?

Comment: Do you mean how do I stop the music? I just bring up my app and click stop.

Comment: @josedlujan, how do I call getDuration from MediaBrowser service?